# "Lock" a block in async function from "concurency"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Even though javascript runs in single thread, concurency issues may still arise in async functions. Some of them may be avoided by greatly increasing the complexity of the code, but some I solve like this:

```
// private "lock"
let _lock = null;
// this function waits till the last call is done, then 
// initiates next one
async function doTheStuff() {
    while (_lock) {
        await _lock;
    }
    _lock = actuallyDoTheStuff();
    const result = await _lock;
    _lock = null;
    return result;
}
async function actuallyDoTheStuff() {
    // this function really does the stuff
}
```

This ensures that only one instance of `actuallyDoTheStuff` is running, but it doesn't really look that nice.

Will this truly work? Can I be sure there will be no endless loop/lock?

And, whether it works or not, isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Whether this approach is working? Or whether there are better alternatives?

Comment: @Bergi Why not both? If it's not working then I'm obviously looking for a better alternative, since I need code that works. If it **is** working, then I'm obviously looking for a better alternative, since I already have a working code.

Comment: You are basically trying to rewrite Promise.prototype.tben using async/await...

Comment: Is the real problem to sequence successive calls to a function?  Because I can think of much nicer ways of doing that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that is the real problem, I need them to happen in the order they were called ideally, to ensure the same resource is not used in parallel. Could you please share your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd encapsulate everything inside `actuallyDoTheStuff`, which simply calls `.then` on the last Promise it generated:

```js
const actuallyDoTheStuff = (() => {
  let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
  return () => {
    const nextProm = lastProm.then(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('resolving');
        resolve();
      }, 1000));
    });
    lastProm = nextProm;
    return lastProm;
  };
})();

console.log('start');
actuallyDoTheStuff();
actuallyDoTheStuff();
actuallyDoTheStuff();
setTimeout(() => {
  actuallyDoTheStuff();
  actuallyDoTheStuff();
}, 200);
```

If it may throw, then add a `catch` when reassigning to `lastProm`

```js
const actuallyDoTheStuff = (() => {
  let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
  return () => {
    const nextProm = lastProm.then(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('resolving');
        resolve();
      }, 1000));
    });
    lastProm = nextProm.catch(() => null);
    return nextProm;
  };
})();

console.log('start');
actuallyDoTheStuff();
actuallyDoTheStuff();
actuallyDoTheStuff();
setTimeout(() => {
  actuallyDoTheStuff();
  actuallyDoTheStuff();
}, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks better, since it enforces particular order of the calls. But I don't understand: How come the `lastProm` variable somehow persists between calls? How come this works without global variable?

Comment: The variable `lastProm` is created in the IIFE in which the inner `actuallyDoTheStuff` is defined. The IIFE runs *immediately*, creates `lastProm` in that scope (visible to the inner arrow function, and nothing else), and then the IIFE returns the function which can be called from the outside. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed a couple of parentheses there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what `actuallyDoTheStuff` eventually should do, but if you're trying to sequence multiple calls of it (and await each call), you could make `doTheStuff` an async wrapper function with a `for loop` that awaits `actuallyDoTheStuff` on each iteration:

```js
function actuallyDoTheStuff( iteration ) {
  console.log( "Waiting...")
  return new Promise( res => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      res( iteration );
    }, 150 );
  } );
}

async function doTheStuff() {
  for ( let i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    const result = await actuallyDoTheStuff( i );
    console.log( result );
  }
}

doTheStuff();
```

Or alternatively make `actuallyDoTheStuff` a recursive function:

```js
let index = 1;
async function actuallyDoTheStuff( i ) {
  if ( i <= 5 ) {
    console.log( "Waiting..." )
    await new Promise( res => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        console.log( i );
        i++
        res();
        actuallyDoTheStuff( i );
      }, 150 );
    } );
  }
}
actuallyDoTheStuff( index );
```